# How do I let Excel share a file as an attachment when Outlook is in a different directory?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook

**Background**

Users are accustomed to sending Excel workbooks as attachments from Excel. Since installing a new version of Outlook in a different directory, this functionality is broken.

**The error**

```
Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 15.0.5153.1000, time stamp: 0x5cff9790
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.24475, time stamp: 0x5cdd8011
Faulting application start time: 0x01d5632a5c44182b
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
```

**What hasn't worked**

So far I have tried both a symbolic link and a hard link for outlook.exe from the folder than contains Excel to the folder than contains Outlook.

```
c:\ExcelFolder>mklink outlook.exe "C:\OutlookFolder\outlook.exe"
```

and

```
c:\ExcelFolder>mklink /H outlook.exe "C:\OutlookFolder\outlook.exe"
```

I ***think*** that the problem stems from Excel trying to launch something other than Outlook since it only needs to attach an email because `kernelbase` is throwing the error.

Can a junction or folder symbolic link be used to *merge* two folders so that the computer treats `c:\ExcelFolder` and `c:\OutlookFolder` like they are the same? Or do I need to look for another solution?

Comment: How did Outlook end up in a non-default location? Did you change the path during installation or was it moved afterwards?

Comment: It's a different version. Think Excel '13 and Outlook '16.

Comment: Did you do anything else that could’ve corrupted the Outlook installation? Because Excel is most certainly not looking for some paths or anything. Usually, it’s using OLE/DDE for stuff like this.

Comment: We have not had any reported incidents outside of this. While I cannot prove it completely, I am _very_ confident that there are no other issues.